# My shortcode doesn't appear in Visual Composer using vc_map

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

I've built a Wordpress plugin, and now I want to add support for Visual Composer but I can't get it to work. I've read a lot of articles about how to use vc_map, found pages on github with examples, and it seems like I do everything like described in these articles. However my shortcodes still don't show up in the VC editor.

My shortcode (it works perfectly as a shortcode, `[mappy id="123"]` will show the map with the ID of 123)

```
add_shortcode('mappy', 'mappy_shortcode');
function mappy_shortcode($atts) {

    // Attribute defaults
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => null,
    ), $atts));

    // Check if id is set, and the given post is a mappy_map
    if(!isset($atts['id'])) {
        return '';
    }
    $post = get_post(intval($atts['id']));
    if(!isset($post)) {
        return;
    }
    if($post->post_type != 'mappy_map') {
        return;
    }

    return $post->post_content;
}
```

And the code I've tried:

```
/**
 * Visual Composer Support
 */
if(defined('WPB_VC_VERSION')) {
    add_action('vc_before_init', 'mappy_vc_support');
}
function mappy_vc_support() {
    vc_map(
        array(
            'base' => 'mappy',
            'description' => __('Display a Mappy map.', 'mappy'),
            'category' => 'Mappy',
            'icon' => plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'img/vc_map_32.png',
            'class' => '',
            'weight' => 100,
            'params' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'dropdown',
                    'class' => '',
                    'heading' => __('Térkép', 'mappy'),
                    'param_name' => 'id',
                    'value' => mappy_map_list(),
                    'description' => __('Térkép', 'mappy'),
                    'holder' => 'div'
                )
            )
        )
    );
}

/**
 * Helper function to get all mappy_map posts
 */
function mappy_map_list() {
    $list = array();
    $posts = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'mappy_map'));
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        $list[$post->post_title] = $post->ID;
    }
    return $list;
}
```

I've also tried to hook `mappy_vc_support` into `init` and `admin_init`, with no luck.

Also note that the function `vc_map` itself is being called, and returns `1`.

What could be the problem here?